# SQL Outer Join Purpose In Specific Case

Tags: mysql

Can someone please explain the difference between:

```
SELECT name
FROM a.table
LEFT OUTER JOIN b.table
ON a.key = b.key;
```

and

```
SELECT name
FROM a.table;
```

I see no differences as both will return all names in table a.table in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query with the join will return duplicate copies of `name`, when there are multiple matches on the key in `b`.

The two queries are not the same.

Comment: Have you tested this on two test tables and examined the results?

Comment: @AcyclicTau . . . I use joins all the time.  This is how they behave.

Comment: Sorry that comment was aimed at the original poster not at you.

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship between Table A and Table B is one-to-one, that is, to say the 'key' in Table B is also a primary key and therefore unique like in Table 'A' then the two are equal.

Table A:

```
  Key      Name
  ----     --------------
   1       George
   2       Lisa
   3       Bill
```

Table B:

```
  Key
  ----
   1
   3
```

Result using your first query would be one below and same as your second query:

```
  Name
  -------
  George
  Lisa
  Bill
```

However, if the relationship is one-to-many, that is, one record Table A could have one or more related records in Table B. And which means the 'key' in Table B is a foreign key then the two are not equal.

Table B:

```
  Key
  ----
   1
   2
   3
   1
   3
```

Result using your first query would be:

```
  Name
  -------
  George
  George
  Lisa
  Bill
  Bill
```

See my [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3744d/2)